# Process changes its PID every second

Tags: windows, windows-10, pid

Today I saw that one process (.NET Runtime Service - mscorsvw.exe) changes its PID really often. When Task Manager refreshes the PID of that process, it is always different. Is that normal? An antivirus program didn't find anything.

Comment: Maybe it is a child process?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36112927/program-that-changes-pid-every-n-seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an optimization service and starts and stops periodically. When it's active, it's running [NGen.exe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_Image_Generator) to optimize .NET assemblies on your machine. It typically only runs in the background, which is probably what is causing the PID to be refreshed every few seconds. It runs off a queue of assemblies that need NGen and therefore is much more active after new installs and after a .NET framework update.

You can run

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\ngen.exe queue status
```

or

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ngen.exe queue status
```

to see what NGen has queued up.

See *[Wondering why mscorsvw.exe has high CPU usage? You can speed it up](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2013/08/06/wondering-why-mscorsvw-exe-has-high-cpu-usage-you-can-speed-it-up/)*.